# Enabling Multiplayer Service in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer, unity3d-unet

Can anyone provide me the solution of how to overcome the event in the black label in the given image??

Here I want to remove the pop-up:- "UNet-powered features are in the process of being deprecated".Can anyone help me as to how to proceed??

Answer (score 1):

UNet is deprecated. You should use alternatives such as Mirror or Photon.